# How are versions and dates formatted?

Tags: translation, software

I'm writing a program and need to know how dates, versions, time, and numbers are formatted in Chinese.

Example (in English):

```
Version 1.0.0 (Build 0)
```

How would that look in Chinese?

Comment: Does the language you're using not handle this automatically, based on the current locale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Micheal's answer is good, but it's from a programmer point of view. Mine's from a Mandarin speaker's point of view.

```
Version: 版本
Major version: 主版本
Minor version: 子版本
Revision: 修正版本
Build: 编译版本
Number: 号
```

According to [Baidu](http://baike.baidu.com/view/421712.htm)

```
GNU Style
　　zh: 主版本号.子版本号[.修正版本号[.编译版本号]]
　　en: Major_Version_Number.Minor_Version_Number[.Revision_Number[.Build_Number]]
　　e.g.: 1.2.1, 2.0, 5.0.0 build-13124

Windows Style
　　zh: 主版本号.子版本号[修正版本号[.编译版本号]]
　　en: Major_Version_Number.Minor_Version_Number[Revision_Number[.Build_Number]]
　　e.g.: 1.21, 2.0

.Net Framework Style
　　zh: 主版本号.子版本号[.编译版本号[.修正版本号]]
　　en: Major_Version_Number.Minor_Version_Number[.Build_Number[.Revision_Number]] 
   e.g.: 1.3.4.2
```

This is a straight copy and paste so I don't take any credit for it. You should be able to match them up individually without needing any knowledge of Chinese.

Comment: Is `版本1.0.0（0编译版本号）` a readable version label for you? I think he's looking for the Chinese equivalent to `Version 1.0.0 (Build 0)`

Comment: I'd probably write it like this (I've never localized any of my software in Chinese, so this is just a guess): 版本1.0.0（编译版本号:0）

Comment: I'm guessing that this is what he's after

Comment: Or he could just write it as: 版本1.0.0.0 :-).

Comment: Fairly certain he could get away with v.1.0.0 (0) without causing too much confusion as well

Comment: If you visit the website for the popular Chinese chat client Tencent QQ, you will see that x.x.x.x or vx.x.x.x are probably the most popular formats out there (instead of using Chinese characters). http://download.digi.tech.qq.com/index.shtml

Comment: 完整翻譯 translated as-is

Comment: @Rony what is? Sorry don't quite understand the relevance of this to this QA.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you should investigate the localization features of your language.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-CN");
string version = strings.Version.replace('%version%', '1.0.0');
version = version.replace('%build%', '0');
Console.WriteLine(version);
```

With the information given in James Jiao's answer & comments, your Chinese version string and its English equivalent could be:

```
版本%version%（编译版本号:%build%）
Version %version% (Build %build%)
```

For more information on localization in C#, refer to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1142840/187954
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/brijrajsingh/glbal_110012005021049AM/glbal_1.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1021kkz0(v=vs.71)